# using threading.timer on django simple lazy object

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-models

If a user does go into a url then `threading.timer` calls a method named `action` with the `request.object`.

```
threading.Timer(60, action, [request.user]).start()
```

Before the call I can find out the user last name by doing:

```
request.user.get_last_name() => the last name is "xxxx"
```

The problem is in the `threading.timer` "action" I get:

```
request.user.get_last_name() => None
```

*Secondly:*

When I do this in the browser it works fine but when I try this in tests there is an exception that it doesn't know table `X`.

```
request.user.get_last_name()
X.objects.filter(name="hello").first()
```

Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code samples you have given in this question there is one potential problem.

You say you are doing: `threading.Timer(60, action, [request.user]).start()` to start the `threading.timer` action. In this case you are passing in the `request.user` this will be an object which contains the logged in users details (or anonymous if not logged in).

Inside the `action` function you say you are calling `request.user.get_last_name()` which results in None.

The issue is you are passing a reference to `request.user` but within the action function using this as if it was a `request` object.

---

You need to change **one** of the following:

1. Your `Action()` - Note I am not using request

   ```
   def action(user):
       user.get_last_name()
   ```

or

2. Your `threading.timer` to be like this - Note I am passing through the request object not request.user:

   ```
   threading.Time(60, action, [request]).start()
   ```